# Need assistance calling variables declared in .net for execution inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, variables, data-conversion

The following variables defined in .net are:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" CssClass="TextTitle"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblOrderNumber" runat="server" CssClass="TextTitle"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" CssClass="TextTitle"></asp:Label>
```

...which need to be passed to JavaScript to track conversions on a checkout "success page":
*The `: "revenue"` is where the asp declared variable's value needs to be called in (revenue, orderId and email) with the labels of the same:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_code.push(["setdata", { "revenue": "revenue"}]);
_code.push(["setdata", { "orderId": "orderId" }]);
_code.push(["setdata", { "email": "email" }]);
_code.push(["convert", "sale" ]);
</script>
```

We've attempted one unsuccessful iteration of the variable recall:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var lblGrandTotal = $('#<%= lblGrandTotal %>');
var lblOrderNumber = $('#<%= lblOrderNumber %>');
var lblEmail = $('#<%= lblEmail %>');

_code.push(["setdata", { "revenue": "lblGrandTotal"}]); 
_code.push(["setdata", { "orderId": "lblOrderNumber" }]);    
_code.push(["setdata", { "email": "lblEmail" }]);
_code.push(["convert", "sale" ]);
</script>
```

and other thoughts would be (but I'm not sure):

As the variable is already declared elsewhere on the "checkout" page, I didn't know if it could just be recalled inside the JS block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_code.push(["setdata", { "revenue": "<%=lblGrandTotal%>"}]);
_code.push(["setdata", { "orderId": "<%= lblOrderNumber %>" }]);
_code.push(["setdata", { "email": "<%= lblEmail %>" }]);
_code.push(["convert", "sale" ]);
</script>
```

...and if that doesn't work, the next thought would have been:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var revenue = "<%= lblGrandTotal %>";
var orderId = "<%= lblOrderNumber %>";
var email = "<%= lblEmail %>";

_code.push(["setdata", { "revenue": "revenue"}]);
_code.push(["setdata", { "orderId": "orderId" }]);
_code.push(["setdata", { "email": "email" }]);
_code.push(["convert", "sale" ]);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance, ya'll are super helpful and I'd appreciate any insight here as I don't have any ASP coding experience and need this for a client.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct below things :

User ClientID for server controls in Javascript `<%= lblGrandTotal.ClientID %>`

To set the value of variable, don't put the *double quotes* *("lblEmail")*. You need to use the actual variable name *(lblEmail)* only. Putting *double quotes* makes it a string value *("lblEmail")* instead of a *variable*.

```
var lblGrandTotal = $('#<%= lblGrandTotal.ClientID %>');//add ClientID
var lblOrderNumber = $('#<%= lblOrderNumber.ClientID %>');//add ClientID
var lblEmail = $('#<%= lblEmail.ClientID %>');//add ClientID

_code.push(["setdata", { "revenue": lblGrandTotal}]); //remove double quotes from lblGrandTotal
_code.push(["setdata", { "orderId": lblOrderNumber }]); //remove double quotes from   
_code.push(["setdata", { "email": lblEmail }]); //remove double quotes from 
_code.push(["convert", "sale" ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I've passed along the code to the client and will follow-up with confirmation if it was a success (looks like it should be).

Cheers!

Comment: Sure, you should practice doing a Unit testing before sending to client ;)

Comment: no go on the code.  Granted, there is a runtime error on the page that wasn't there before (doubtful it has anything to do with this) and I'll need to confirm where these variables are actually being declared earlier in the page...

More to follow (unless there are other ideas).